# Cmake error during building a rospackage

Tags: ros-kinetic, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all

I am trying to learn how to use the ROS-PCL library with the Velodyne 64E lidar. I have stored my code in the same directory as that of the Velodyne_height_map project and I want to modify the existing CMakeList.txt file to incorporate my own code.
My main goal is to find the distances of the obstacles by subscribing to the velodyne_obstacles topic.

This is the error I am getting when I am building the project.

```
>  *** No rule to make target
> '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libpcl_ros_filters.so',
> needed by
> '/home/aditya/catkin_ws/devel/lib/velodyne_height_map/myheight'.
> Stop.
```

This is the addition I have done to the CMakeLists.txt file by following few tutorials.

```
add_executable(myheight src/my_height_sub.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myheight ${catkin_LIBRARIES}${catkin_LIBRARIES}
                      ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
                      ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

This is the program I am trying to run.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> PointCloud;

void callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr&);


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    std::string topic = nh.resolveName("point_cloud");
    uint32_t queue_size = 1;
    
    
    // to create a subscriber, you can do this (as above):
    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("velodyne_points", queue_size, callback);
}
```

I know I am missing some dependencies in the CMakelists, but cant seem to figure out what they are.
Can someone help me out please? Many thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289799/cmake-error-during-building-a-rospackage/) by [aditya369007](https://answers.ros.org/users/30739/aditya369007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2018-04-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-04-27**:
I'm no expert on this, but it seems that `pcl_ros_filter` (which is in your error message) [cannot be used](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues/16). Why this should be linked, however, I don't know. I don't see anything apparent relating to that.

**Comment by [aditya369007](https://answers.ros.org/users/30739/aditya369007/) on 2018-04-27**:
Thats what I am unable to understand, I have not used `pcl_ros_filter` still this is showing up.
But I have still added `${PCL_ROS_FILTER}` in the link libraries, but still I am facing the same error.

**Comment by [robotchicken](https://answers.ros.org/users/34838/robotchicken/) on 2018-04-27**:
Can you paste the entire CMakeList.txt(without the comments)?

**Comment by [aditya369007](https://answers.ros.org/users/30739/aditya369007/) on 2018-04-27**:
[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/9PxLsTAA)

It is attached here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libpcl_ros_filters.so
This path seems super wierd. Can you paste the result of "echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH" on you terminal.

Was this a CmakeList.txt file written by you?
can you try changing to:

```
target_link_libraries(
          myheight
          ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
          ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
          ${PCL_LIBRARIES} 
)
```

---

Originally posted by [robotchicken](https://answers.ros.org/users/34838/robotchicken/) with karma: 51 on 2018-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aditya369007](https://answers.ros.org/users/30739/aditya369007/) on 2018-04-27**:
In function `main': /home/aditya/catkin_ws/src/velodyne_height_map/src/my_height_sub.cpp:16: undefined reference to` callback(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_std::allocator<void > const> const&)'

I got this error now I think its a programming error. Will rectify it

**Comment by [aditya369007](https://answers.ros.org/users/30739/aditya369007/) on 2018-04-27**:
And no this was not written by me

**Comment by [robotchicken](https://answers.ros.org/users/34838/robotchicken/) on 2018-04-27**:
Yup, i think you need to define the function callback.

**Comment by [robotchicken](https://answers.ros.org/users/34838/robotchicken/) on 2018-04-27**:
Mark as resolved if it works out.